# compiling a shared library

Tags: application-development, shared-library, dynamic-linking

I'm doing a 64-bit rewrite of some code I wrote that implements a novel approach to genetic algorithms that I want to turn into a shared library exclusive to Ubuntu using code::blocks/gcc.

I have successfully made the project using the shared library stationary and when I compile I get my .so file. So far so good.

Now I seem to remember I need an import library in order to link to the code in .so from my caller programme and there is an option for this checked in Project->Properties->Build targets.

I think I am along the right track, but my question is what do I do next? Where does the import library go and what do I need to do in my caller programme to call the code.

Also am I right to think I can export classes as well as just variables and functions? If so how do I declare the exported code and the imports in the caller code?